# Stop bad behaving sites from behaving bad (firefox)?

Tags: firefox, browser, tabs

Just a question, that triggers me for years now.

More and more sites are changing the browser behaviour or manipulating in some way. Here a list, what needs to be changed/removed:

- clicking on an ad infected page: Play Video opens the same page in a new tab and in the old tab gets redirected 5 billion times till I end up ad an ad or even worse site. How to stop this? I mean, why does firefox even allow more than 3 redirections in a row? That is just useless. No good site should ever require that. If so, it is not a good site. Is there a way to fix that?
- Changing context menue: Some entries get removed on some sites. I do not accept that. It is like putting my hands in chains, while I am in the museum or what place ever. I have no problem with added entries, if they are marked as such. But do not take away my features! How to fix that?
- Some pages even stop you from right clicking alltogether and show a message like "Stop we have small sticks and want you to not copy our text". No, I do not want that. When I click something, the menu has to open. There is no other acceptable situiation.
- Some ad infected pages open ads in new windows. Why does firefox open a new window anyway? I did not tell it to do so. If I want a new window, I tell firefox to open one. So how to stop it, since this "feature", which I call "critical and insecure error and/or mistake", actually makes no sense at all? (It really does not make sense. Most people with more than 5 mins of experience will work Tab-based. So no need for new windows usually - except you want it, you can click it of course)

It would really improofe my life, if you could tell me how to fix this "for many years annoying problems"

Oh, and almost forgot: If i can archive this without plugins (Greasmonkey and similar is okay however) it would be nice. Plugins really slow a browser with 200 tabs open. Well, 20 by now, but you understand for sure.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: You are right. I removed everything, that does not have to do with webpage behaviour. Now it is basically only Javascript related.

I hope, this is okay? Still more than 1 problem - but they are related and belong to the heading.

Comment: 1 and 4: Because they are abusing countermeasures that are already in place. 2 and 3: because it's actually useful for some websites to replace context menu with a custom one (eg. Google Drive).

Comment: I already said, it is no problem if it adds new entries. I still want the standard buttons to be there.

1+4: Maybe there are not enought. Why can a site redirect 10 times? This does not make sense to me. Why would I ever want that? Just block sites from redirecting without my permission. Maybe some custom behaviour: if site https://x.y.z opens a new tab and the original tab changes its adress without my interaction, stop this action or even close the first tab. I mean, many sites do this and it would be easy to implement from a scripting point.
4: How *can* a Site open a new window?

Comment: I think I am out of luck with that. Firefox is dieing. There have not been any improofments in plain usability for... what. Like 10 years now? Only thing that was *very, very* nice: "Do not play video until tab is selected". Do not remember the correct term.

Comment: You don't realize how many legitimate redirects happen without your knowledge. Having to confirm all of them would be hell. You also don't seem to know that APIs to open new windows have been there for a long time and there are some legitimate reasons to use them. Popup blocking is a newer invention to fight abuse of these APIs. There are, on the other hand, no APIs to add entries to context menus. Your question is in a large part wishful thinking. The need for support of legacy standards adds a great inertia to web development, you can't just change these things overnight.

Comment: Well, I know it is possible fore 10+ years, yeah. But I actually never had a single situation, where I needed to open a new window. Only, when opening a PDF - which would be easy to detect and therefore allow.

And I do not like redirections at all. I mean, it can be good to redirect from youtubee.com to youtube.com to avoid viruses. And youtube will likely refer to an IP somewhere. Just tell me, why I especially need a redirection on such a site? Just tell me an example, where 5 redirections are neccesary for *me* and I believe you.